# Validate e-mail address based on previous orders before adding product to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-validation

I have added a custom text-field on the single product page with the "[PPOM for WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bulk-order-form-for-woocommerce/)" plugin

The intention here is that the user enters his e-mail address and then clicks on the "add-to-cart" button

But before adding the product to his card, I want to check on the basis of the e-mail address whether this already occurs in the existing orders

I already found out about using a filter like `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` to accomplish what I want to do but to be honest, that is how far I got

```php
function validate_email( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {
    // TODO: Collect all previous orders using the entered email address and check if this already exists in the DB

    wc_add_notice( __( 'E-Mail Address already sold', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_email', 10, 5 );
```

---

It would be great if anyone could give me some guidance on how to accomplish that

Comment: How do you save previous emails? It is important to know how to purchase email in order to provide a solution based on your previous code. There is no solution without knowing how you saved the previous emails.

Comment: Dear Hamid, thanks for your response. I thought all orders are saved in a orders-database by woocommerce within Wordpress. That’s where I planned to get them from. From there I export those into our internal management system (but there is no API or so to get them from there later on). Do you think that‘s possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't use the (paid) plugin that you use, so in my answer, I add a field via custom code to the single product page
- After entering an email address, some validation will take place (not empty, valid email), this can be further expanded to your needs
- If the email address is valid, all previous orders with that email address will be read from the database

  - [wc_get_orders()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) is used for this, this can be further expanded with additional parameters such as certain order statuses, etc.
- If the product ID you want to add to the shopping cart is present in previous orders (with customer email), an error message will be displayed.

So you get:

```php
// Add input field to single product page
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button() {
    echo '<div class="custom-field-wrapper">';
    echo '<label for="customer-email">Enter your email:</label>';
    echo '<input type="email" id="customer-email" name="customer-email">';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );

// Validate
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Isset
    if ( isset ( $_POST['customer-email'] ) ) {
        // Sanitize
        $customer_email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customer-email'] );
        
        // Empty
        if ( empty ( $customer_email ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a value into the field', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            $passed = false;
            
        // Verifies that an email is valid.
        // NOT valid
        } elseif ( ! is_email( $customer_email ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid email address', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            $passed = false;
        } else {
            // Get orders by email
            $orders_by_customer_email = wc_get_orders( array(
                'customer' => $customer_email,
            ));
            
            // Set flag
            $flag = false;
            
            // This function is an alias of count()
            if ( sizeof( $orders_by_customer_email ) > 0 ) {
                // Iterating through each order
                foreach ( $orders_by_customer_email as $order ) {
                    // Going through order items
                    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                        // Get product ID
                        $product_id_in_order = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
                    
                        // Compare
                        if ( $product_id_in_order == $product_id ) {
                            $flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // True
            if ( $flag ) {
                wc_add_notice( __( 'You have already purchased this product before', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                $passed = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

---

**Note:** if it is not specifically about the current product ID, but about all  previously sold items

Replace this part

```php
// This function is an alias of count()
if ( sizeof( $orders_by_customer_email ) > 0 ) {
    // Iterating through each order
    foreach ( $orders_by_customer_email as $order ) {
        // Going through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Get product ID
            $product_id_in_order = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
        
            // Compare
            if ( $product_id_in_order == $product_id ) {
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// True
if ( $flag ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'You have already purchased this product before', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    $passed = false;
}
```

With

```php
// This function is an alias of count()
if ( sizeof( $orders_by_customer_email ) > 0 ) {
    $flag = true;
}

// True
if ( $flag ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'You have already purchased something before', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    $passed = false;
}
```